# How can I get link in href with specified class by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

Here are the html details:

```
<div class="aaa">
   <span class="bbb"></span>
      <a data-track-id="Google Map" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//18/@1813z" target="_blank" class="ccc">Google Map</a>
</div>
```

I would like to get only latitude and longitude which are 18 and 1813z how could I do that?

I'm using two url pages for getting text in the secondpage. The other info like Title or Name work as it appears as text so I can use `get_text().`

But this case, I could not get the link after href. So I  Please help.

The code I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

def get_page(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    mainpage = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    return mainpage

mainpage = get_page('https://www.something.com')
mainpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(mainpage,'html.parser')
secondpage = get_page('https://www.something2.com/')
secondpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(secondpage,'html.parser')

try:
     for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('a',{"data-track-id":"Google Map"}, href=True): 
         gpslocation = gps['href'] 
     print(gpslocation) 
except:
     print(gpslocation)
```

Comment: Fix your quotes and indentation

Comment: How did the code fail?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I fixed it, thank you, but my code still doesn't work. It doesn't show any error but there is no text or link appear after I run it.

Comment: You did not fix it. Please edit the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for reminding. But it still appears nothing after I run.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Could I send the whole file to you?

Comment: No you may not.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I do apologize if it isn't appropriate. I've tried this way as well but still no text appear unlike other parts.
  gpsloca = []
    for gpsloca in (secondpage_parser.find_all("div", {"class":"aaa"})):
        for gps in gpsloca.find("a", {"data-track-id":"Google Map"}):
            gpsloca.get("href")  
print(str(gpsloca)) 
I do not know why it still has no result.

Comment: It is difficult to recreate your problem and help without knowing the correct URLs to use.

Comment: @MartinEvans Here are the urls. This is the mainpage: https://www.wongnai.com/businesses?domain=1&page.number=1&sort.type=8&regions=373   and here is second page: https://www.wongnai.com/restaurants/thebarnsteakhousechiangmai?_st=cD0wO2I9Mjc0MzU0O2FkPXRydWU7dD0xNTM2NDE4MzIxOTM1O2k9NDk3MWEyZGQtMDY5Mi00MDU2LWExZmUtZmE5Y2ZlMjVhODYwO3dyZWY9c3I7&wref=sr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the page is generated dynamically with JavaScript, if you print secondpage_parser you will find that the line

```
<a data-track-id="Google Map" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//18/@1813z" target="_blank" class="ccc">Google Map</a>
```

does not exist in the raw source. You say you want the latitude and longitude, you can get that from the map image attributes like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def get_page(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    mainpage = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    return mainpage

mainpage = get_page('https://www.wongnai.com/businesses?domain=1&page.number=1&sort.type=8&regions=373')
mainpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(mainpage,'html.parser')
secondpage = get_page('https://www.wongnai.com/restaurants/thebarnsteakhousechiangmai?_st=cD0wO2I9Mjc0MzU0O2FkPXRydWU7dD0xNTM2NDE4MzIxOTM1O2k9NDk3MWEyZGQtMDY5Mi00MDU2LWExZmUtZmE5Y2ZlMjVhODYwO3dyZWY9c3I7&wref=sr')
secondpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(secondpage,'html.parser')

try:
     for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('img',{"alt":"map"}, srcset=True):
         parsed_url = urlparse(gps['srcset'])
         mykeys = ['lat', 'lon']
         gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.query)[k][0] for k in mykeys]
     print(gpslocation)
except:
     print(gpslocation)
```

Outputs:

```
['18.832687', '98.998473']
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!